# FindExternalEvaluators['Python"] returns a blank box instead of the locations or python versions

Tags: python, external-calls, julia

I'm using Mathematica 12.0 Student Edition and have python 3.7.6 instilled in anaconda and 3.7.8 installed via Microsoft Store. I have followed the reference instructions [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ConfigurePythonForExternalEvaluate.html) but to no avail. The following is all that is displayed after opening Mathematica and attempting to locate python.

[image]

Is there something with `$Path` that I'm missing?

The documentation seems to suggest that the steps in the link listed above are all I need to follow. I cant find anyone else with this issue so any and all help is greatly appreciated.

---

I tried the same thing with Julia (1.5.0), follwing the instructions found [Here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ConfigureJuliaForExternalEvaluate.html), but I also get this instead:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you need to register the location of `Python` manually:

```
RegisterExternalEvaluator["Python","D:\\Python3\\python.exe"]
```

Comment: Yeah, that did it. Thank you!

I tried this earlier and it didn't work so I'm at a loss as for why it suddenly decided to start working now. :/

Also, Julia is only experimentally available in 12.1 not 12.0